# LLVM - Cant Link Support Librarys/Linker Erros When Using LLVM-13 with Conan

Tags: c++, gcc, llvm, linker-errors, llvm-c++-api

I am using the [LLVM conan package](https://conan.io/center/llvm-core) to build my compiler, and so far it has gone great, up until I have been trying to use `llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple` and `llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget`. I am getting undefined references to both. Both from seem to be from the LLVM Support library, and at least `llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple` appears to be automatically generated (I found the `.inc` source for it on my system). Conan seems to tell CMake to link in the LLVM Support library as I can see it being passed to the linker when I try to build and get the error (e.g) `-lLLVMSupport`. I saw some people had linker errors with this in the past when switching to GCC 5 with LLVM 3/4. But this is LLVM-13.0.0 and gcc-12.0.1. Conan I see [warns about C++ ABI compatibility with GCC-5](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.36/getting_started.html)

I changed the setting on my profile, but not change (yet). I may try rebuilding LLVM and updating this post.

I really need to get this in an a few hours, is there

1. A way to by-hand know what the triplet string should be for my operating system? I [saw the format here](https://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm_1_1sys.html#ae329f3571e25025c5496be7a9746a94f). It appears to be based off of a macro? Will `gcc -dumpmachine` suffice?
2. How feasible is it to use this to generate a "target" by hand, [I am reverse-engineering this](https://llvm.org/doxygen/structllvm_1_1TargetRegistry.html#a5580434a3d20841cbcb73e9c8c80956b)
3. The primary question, how can I fix this error and linke to `llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple` and `llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget`

Here is the full log:

```
root@3129d254c74c:~/workdir/compilerbuild# ninja warp_compiler
[2/2] Linking CXX executable bin/warp_compiler
FAILED: bin/warp_compiler 
: && /usr/bin/c++   CMakeFiles/warp_compiler.dir/Compiler/Compile.cpp.o CMakeFiles/warp_compiler.dir/Compiler/FunctionParser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/warp_compiler.dir/Compiler/Main.cpp.o -o bin/warp_compiler -L/root/.conan/data/cpputest/4.0/_/_/package/7f06ab4d29b1f14af224d13dc05f362c6832ed41/lib   -L/root/.conan/data/llvm-core/13.0.0/_/_/package/6efbb14f313e71b5e1dbf77c1c011f47614b7c7c/lib   -L/root/.conan/data/libxml2/2.9.10/_/_/package/c4a7cacf01760cbd7354b11a55bf653f7df2bf5d/lib   -L/root/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.12/_/_/package/2a19826344ff00be1c04403f2f8e7008ed3a7cc6/lib   -L/root/.conan/data/libiconv/1.17/_/_/package/2a19826344ff00be1c04403f2f8e7008ed3a7cc6/lib -Wl,-rpath,/root/.conan/data/cpputest/4.0/_/_/package/7f06ab4d29b1f14af224d13dc05f362c6832ed41/lib:/root/.conan/data/llvm-core/13.0.0/_/_/package/6efbb14f313e71b5e1dbf77c1c011f47614b7c7c/lib:/root/.conan/data/libxml2/2.9.10/_/_/package/c4a7cacf01760cbd7354b11a55bf653f7df2bf5d/lib:/root/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.12/_/_/package/2a19826344ff00be1c04403f2f8e7008ed3a7cc6/lib:/root/.conan/data/libiconv/1.17/_/_/package/2a19826344ff00be1c04403f2f8e7008ed3a7cc6/lib  lib/liblibwarp.a  -lCppUTestExt  -lCppUTest  -lLLVMTableGenGlobalISel  -lLLVMTableGen  -lLLVMFileCheck  -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser  -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen  -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler  -lLLVMAArch64Desc  -lLLVMAArch64Info  -lLLVMAArch64Utils  -lLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser  -lLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen  -lLLVMMIRParser  -lLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler  -lLLVMAMDGPUDesc  -lLLVMAMDGPUInfo  -lLLVMAMDGPUUtils  -lLLVMARMAsmParser  -lLLVMARMCodeGen  -lLLVMARMDisassembler  -lLLVMARMDesc  -lLLVMARMInfo  -lLLVMARMUtils  -lLLVMAVRAsmParser  -lLLVMAVRCodeGen  -lLLVMAVRDesc  -lLLVMAVRDisassembler  -lLLVMAVRInfo  -lLLVMBPFAsmParser  -lLLVMBPFCodeGen  -lLLVMBPFDesc  -lLLVMBPFDisassembler  -lLLVMBPFInfo  -lLLVMCoverage  -lLLVMDWARFLinker  -lLLVMDWP  -lLLVMDebugInfoGSYM  -lLLVMDlltoolDriver  -lLLVMFrontendOpenACC  -lLLVMFuzzMutate  -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen  -lLLVMHexagonAsmParser  -lLLVMHexagonDisassembler  -lLLVMHexagonDesc  -lLLVMHexagonInfo  -lLLVMInterfaceStub  -lLLVMInterpreter  -lLLVMLTO  -lLLVMExtensions  -lLLVMLanaiCodeGen  -lLLVMLanaiAsmParser  -lLLVMLanaiDisassembler  -lLLVMLanaiDesc  -lLLVMLanaiInfo  -lLLVMLibDriver  -lLLVMOption  -lLLVMLineEditor  -lLLVMMCA  -lLLVMMCJIT  -lLLVMMSP430AsmParser  -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen  -lLLVMMSP430Desc  -lLLVMMSP430Disassembler  -lLLVMMSP430Info  -lLLVMMipsAsmParser  -lLLVMMipsCodeGen  -lLLVMMipsDesc  -lLLVMMipsDisassembler  -lLLVMMipsInfo  -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen  -lLLVMNVPTXDesc  -lLLVMNVPTXInfo  -lLLVMObjectYAML  -lLLVMOrcJIT  -lLLVMPasses  -lLLVMCoroutines  -lLLVMipo  -lLLVMFrontendOpenMP  -lLLVMIRReader  -lLLVMAsmParser  -lLLVMInstrumentation  -lLLVMLinker  -lLLVMVectorize  -lLLVMObjCARCOpts  -lLLVMExecutionEngine  -lLLVMRuntimeDyld  -lLLVMJITLink  -lLLVMOrcTargetProcess  -lLLVMOrcShared  -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser  -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen  -lLLVMPowerPCDesc  -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler  -lLLVMPowerPCInfo  -lLLVMRISCVAsmParser  -lLLVMRISCVCodeGen  -lLLVMRISCVDisassembler  -lLLVMRISCVDesc  -lLLVMRISCVInfo  -lLLVMSparcAsmParser  -lLLVMSparcCodeGen  -lLLVMSparcDesc  -lLLVMSparcDisassembler  -lLLVMSparcInfo  -lLLVMSymbolize  -lLLVMDebugInfoPDB  -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser  -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen  -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler  -lLLVMSystemZDesc  -lLLVMSystemZInfo  -lLLVMWebAssemblyAsmParser  -lLLVMWebAssemblyCodeGen  -lLLVMWebAssemblyDisassembler  -lLLVMWebAssemblyDesc  -lLLVMWebAssemblyInfo  -lLLVMWebAssemblyUtils  -lLLVMWindowsManifest  -lLLVMX86AsmParser  -lLLVMX86CodeGen  -lLLVMCFGuard  -lLLVMGlobalISel  -lLLVMX86Desc  -lLLVMX86Disassembler  -lLLVMX86Info  -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen  -lLLVMAsmPrinter  -lLLVMDebugInfoDWARF  -lLLVMDebugInfoMSF  -lLLVMSelectionDAG  -lLLVMCodeGen  -lLLVMBitWriter  -lLLVMScalarOpts  -lLLVMAggressiveInstCombine  -lLLVMInstCombine  -lLLVMTransformUtils  -lLLVMTarget  -lLLVMAnalysis  -lLLVMProfileData  -lLLVMXCoreDesc  -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler  -lLLVMMCDisassembler  -lLLVMXCoreInfo  -lLLVMXRay  -lLLVMObject  -lLLVMMCParser  -lLLVMMC  -lLLVMDebugInfoCodeView  -lLLVMBitReader  -lLLVMCore  -lLLVMRemarks  -lLLVMBitstreamReader  -lLLVMTextAPI  -lLLVMBinaryFormat  -lLLVMSupport  -lLLVMDemangle  -lxml2  -lz  -liconv  -lcharset  -ldl  -lrt  -lm  -lpthread && :
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/warp_compiler.dir/Compiler/Compile.cpp.o: in function `Warp::SyntaxTranslation::LLVM::initialize_target(llvm::Module&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, llvm::TargetOptions, llvm::Optional<llvm::Reloc::Model>)':
Compile.cpp:(.text+0x1534): undefined reference to `llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/warp_compiler.dir/Compiler/Main.cpp.o: in function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text+0xf46): undefined reference to `llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

It was using the old libstdcxx, I ran:

```
conan profile update settings.compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 default
```

And then edited my conanfile.txt to just contain the reference to `llvm-core/13.0.0` and ran

```
conan install .. --build=llvm-core
```

And now it works!